# Using await useAsyncQuery() is returning null in the browser but shows the data value in terminal when console.log(data.value)

Tags: graphql, apollo, strapi, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm using Nuxt 3 and fetching data from Strapi with Apollo and graphQL.
I have used this similar setup with Prepr in the past with no issues.

My GraphQL query is correct and it is returning data but the problem is in the timing. here's the code I'm using in my page in Nuxt inside `<script setup>`

```
const { data, error, refresh } = await useAsyncQuery({
    query: GetProjectByID,
    variables: {
      id: 1,
    },
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(data)
}, 100);
  console.log(data)
```

in the screenshot below, you can see these 2 console logs. in the first log the refImpl shows the value as null but when I expand it I can see that there's an object in value

If I use `console.log(data.value)` I get null in the browser but I get the correct object in the development terminal

[image]

What am I doing wrong? what's the reason for this behaviour?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I was able to find where the issue was. In my front-end I had these 3 packages installed

```
    "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
```

`graphql@16.8.1` was already installed as a dependency of `nuxtjs/apollo`. So,
When I uninstalled `graphql` and `graphql-tag` leaving `"@nuxtjs/apollo": "^5.0.0-alpha.7"` in my package.json, I started getting the data without a problem.
This might have been a version clash, but at least now it's working fine.